# Wordpress: Set and Get theme colors

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How would I go about defining more colors for my custom theme, in this area (Appearance > Customize > Colors)?

[image: Theme color settings]

I would like to add things like

- Primary
- Light-primary
- Urgent
- Alert

To be defined in this area. Where users can freely choose the color like it already is for **Header Text Color** and **Background Color**

And once defined, how would I go about accessing them?

Comment: [wpengine.com: How to add options to the WordPress Customizer](https://wpengine.com/resources/how-to-add-options-to-the-wordpress-customizer/)

Comment: @CBroe Honestly all I got from that link is that you sh/could use customizer.php to do it. I'm no closer to actually adding more colors to the pre-existing ones. In a way where I can access them myself and blocks will recognise them as default color options.

Comment: The article explains how you can add your own custom options. They are using a new custom "logo" option there, that uses the `WP_Customize_Image_Control` to provide the UI element - so there is probably a similar class for the color picker control available as well. (And if not, you can still create your own control using `WP_Customize_Control`.) And to then fetch those configured values in your code somewhere, you would use `get_theme_mod`.

Comment: And https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/ provides some more info on how the whole thing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function ( $wp_customize ) {
    $key = "New Custom Color";
    $value = "#f3f3f3";

    $wp_customize->add_setting($key, array(
        'default'           => $value,
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, $key, array(
        'label'    => ucfirst($key), 
        'section'  => 'colors',
        'settings' => $key, 
    )));
});
```